# Why does mongoose updateOne throw proxy error?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose

I have a simple mern application. There is basically a form. Upon submitting it the backend api runs which updates the user document present in mongo db. 
The problem I ran into is when I write the following query, it throws a nasty error **Could not proxy request /api/auth/fb/register/patient from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000/.**

```
router.post('/auth/fb/register/patient', (req,res) => {
User.updateOne({email: req.body.email}, { role: "patient"})
})
```

I thought the route is wrong or something but if instead of the update query I run the find query it works perfectly. The following is the find query that does not give any error:

```
router.post('/auth/fb/register/patient', (req,res) => {
  User.findOne({email: req.body.email}).then(user => console.log(user))
})
```

Does anyone know why update specifically does not work?

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable http  cross origin

```
     app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "YOUR-DOMAIN.TLD"); 
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, 
      Accept");
      next();
    });

    app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
     // Handle the get for this route
    });`enter code here`

    app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
      // Handle the post for this route
    });
```